# See if a number is within range of 10 or 30 in hot or cold game

Tags: javascript, range

I'm working on a game where you have to guess a number, and if it matches the number that is randomly generated then you win. I've got most of the game completed apart from the part where you have to check if the guessed number is within the range of 30 or 10 of the randomly generated number. To give an example, if the random number is 50 and the guessed number is 60 then this is within a range of 10 of the random number and this should therefore cause the screen to turn to the colour red, because they are 'hot' but iv'e been having trouble working out the calculation for it. Any ideas?
This is the code I'm using to calculate if the number is correct or not.

```
function guessFunction() {
    counter++;
    document.getElementById("guessNumber").innerHTML = counter;
    if (!checkEqual(document.getElementById("randomNumber"), random)) {
        document.body.style.background = "orange";
    } else {
        document.body.style.background = "green";
        document.getElementById("another").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    if (!checkHigher(document.getElementById("randomNumber"), random)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    if (!checkGreater(document.getElementById("randomNumber"),
            random)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

function checkHigher(element1, element2) {
    if (element1.value > element2) {
        document.getElementById("highOrLow").innerHTML = "Too High";
    } else if (element1.value == element2) {
        document.getElementById("highOrLow").innerHTML = "got it";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("highOrLow").innerHTML = "Too low";
    }
}
```

Comment: So subtract the guess and number and you got the difference and check the ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically subtract the two and get the absolute value to find the difference. On another note I see you have multiple functions for testing different cases. You could write one function to handle all cases and only pass the generated number and guess in instead of the elements themselves. Then it is more stand alone. Something like this:

```
function checkNumber(number, guess) {
    // Gets difference by subtracting and finding absolute value
    var diff = Math.abs(number - guess);

    // Assumes guess is too low and checks if its higher
    var highlow = " and too low";
    if (guess > number) {
        highlow = " and too high";
    }

    // Checks range for hot and cold while adding in high or lowness, else its exact so ignores adding high or lowness
    // Off by more than 20 cold, off by under 20 hot.
    if (diff >= 21) {
        document.getElementById("highOrLow").innerHTML = "Cold" + highlow;
    } else if (diff >= 1 && diff <= 20) {
        document.getElementById("highOrLow").innerHTML = "Hot" + highlow;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("highOrLow").innerHTML = "Got it";
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bohxapdw/2/